# Can I create multiple instances of the MsalService

Tags: angular, azure-ad-msal

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular

I have a single client app that wants to talk to several different backend rest apis each of which accepts different azure client ids.

Is it possible to create multiple instances of MsalService configured for each of these backends?

I'm asking because I don't see any related examples or docs and I'm worried about the behind-the-scenes caching of things causing troubles.

Comment: are the different client ids needed in the same view/state?

Comment: the rest services will be called from different angular services.  more than one of these angular services may be used by the same view

Comment: What @alphapilgrim is asking (correct me if I'm wrong). Will the client be registered more than once and will have multiple client id as a front-end? If no and both back-ends are registered with the same Azure AD you do not need multiple instances of MsalService

Comment: here's my understanding (i'm trying to figure this out)...

the rest apis are developed by different teams.  each team gets a different azure client id they use when they connect their client to their rest apis.

now i want to build an uber client that can talk to multiple teams' rest apis.  i think i need an instance of MsalService for each rest api so i can specify the corresponding client id.

Answer (score 0):

You need to register your front-end and give it access to the registered APIs

```
export const protectedResourceMap:[string, string[]][]=
[
 ['https://API1',['api://.../access_as_user']] , 
 ['https://API2',['api://.../access_as_user']] ,
 ['https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me', ['user.read']] 
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ MsalModule.forRoot({
                  clientID: Your client ID,
                  protectedResourceMap : protectedResourceMap
                })]
           })
```

You will configure the interceptor, so it will choose the right token to use

```
providers: [ ProductService, {
        provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
        useClass: MsalInterceptor,
        multi: true
    }
   ],
```

[Source](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-angular)

Comment: what do i do if API2 only accepts a different client id?

Comment: Are you registering your front-end with two different tenants ? what does "accepts a different client id" mean for you?

Comment: i believe that the client id is used on the front end to acquire the token and on the backend to validate the token.  it is used to get the validation keys from azure.

api2 has been created to validate a different client id.  if i want to call both api1 and api2, i need to be able to acquire two different tokens from azure and pass the correct token to each of the backend rest apis

Comment: it looks like azure calls it "application id" when i look in portal.azure.com / Azure Active Directory / Enterprise Applications / my-app